How to interact with ERC-721 (NFT) tokens using the Safe SDK?
How can I interact (list, transfer) with ERC-721 tokens using the Safe SDK?
I see that the .getTokeList from the API library only lists ERC-20 tokens and that the .getBalance from the protocol kit returns the ETH balance of the Safe.
I am looking for a way to list out the NFT's in the Safe and being able to transfer them programmatically (obviously as a Safe transaction, respecting the threshold, signers, etc).
Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks a lot for your good answer.
Unfortunately, Safe does not offer a native way to list NFTs (ERC-721 tokens). You have to program this yourself.
To do this, you would have to create and maintain a list of ERC-721 contracts, check the ownership of every Safe, and track the transfer events.
Please be aware that several services to get the NFTs of an address exist; a short research on the internet will help you to find them.
I hope this answers your question; please mark your question as answered or write a follow-up comment.
All the best!
